# Качество кода PHP

Tags: php

Прошу взглянуть на мою конструкцию для проверки на наличие различий между формой ввода и БД, и при их нахождении обновить требуемую запись. Чтобы тупо не копировать условие с подстановкой разных названий написал вот это:

```
function saveData() {
      global $row;
      $saveType = array(
          1 => "firstname",
          2 => "lastname",
          3 => "address",
          4 => "zipcity",
          5 => "country",
        );
      for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
        if ($row[$saveType[$i]] != $_POST[$saveType[$i]]) {
          $result = mysql_query("UPDATE phonebook_data SET {$saveType[$i]} =    '{$_POST[$saveType[$i]]}' WHERE id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'");
        }
      }
    }
```

Прошу совета, как можно лучше? И вообще меня смущает мой запрос. Вернее способ подстановки переменных в нем. Так вообще можно делать?

Comment: В запросы данные так подставлять однозначно не стоит, читай про sql-инъекции, а ещё лучше юзай pdo. PS: если в массиве можно указать иднекс только для первого элемента, все остальные индексы пойдут за ним

Comment: `Качество кода PHP ` - не айс) читай коммент выше)

Comment: А почему нельзя обновлять без проверки? Поля если не изменились, то mysql их вроде как не обновляет - экономится время на запросе, чем если вы будете их проверять.

И еще - раз вы отобразили данные, значит вы их уже получили из БД. А если их сохранять отдельно, а потом сравнивать полученные от пользователя с сохраненными из БД? Чем не вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не совсем правильный подход.
Представим что у вас придут все данные измененные - в итоге 5 запросов. А если полей будет допустим >10.
Нада сделать построитель запроса, так дже для сравнения массивов лучше воспользоватся обширными функциями php для работы с ними.

И еще я правильно понимаю что массив $saveType  содержит наименования полей которые может изменить юзер, но на самом деле их больше?

Answer (score 1):

Можно следующим образом поступить, если уж очень хочется проверить изменилсь данные или нет.
 1. Пользователь получает из БД данные в форму
 2. Из них делаем строку md5(все переменные полученные из бд)
 3. Полученное значение пишем в input type hidden
 4. Отправляем форму
 5. Из полученных данных также делаем md5(все переменные полученные из бд)
 6. Сверяем хэши, если они разные делаем обновление БД, если нет значит ничего не изменилось и ничего не делаем.

Comment: @Зоркий, узрел мой коммент))

Comment: а если вам юзер хэши изменит? как можно доверять данным прищедших со стороны?

Comment: @Ale_x, ну и чего страшного случится? Лишний раз данные запишутся в базу. 

Все равно, ведь если юзер их действительно изменил, то   мы их пишем.

Comment: тогда зачем лишнюю работу то делать?))

Comment: @Ale_x, в каком случае лишнюю работу? Я бы вообще хэши не считал, а просто отправляемые значения клал в хидден. А по приему формы сранивал посимвольно. Не совпало, запишем новые в базу (только все одним  запросом). Это было бы и быстрее и проще всего.

Comment: да банальная ситуация,2 юзера начали править одну запись- причем все взяли изначально одинаковые значения, (хиддены, кешы у всех одинаково) - один исправил, другойеще не успел отправить данные, пошел покурил - приходит - и думает а ниче менять не буду - мне такие как есть данные и нада - то есть он фактически ждет что они и сохранятся - как тут ваши хеши, хиддены отработают?

Comment: @Ale_x, о проблеме совместной модификации данных (в частности о локах, транзакциях и т.п.)  в вопросе не было ни слова.

Это отдельная задача, котрая здесь просто не рассматривается.